# How to do an INNER JOIN, GROUP BY, HAVING COUNT() with n-to-n tables in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

How can I write this SQL query in EF Core 7 (underlying DB is PostgreSQL)?

```sql
SELECT q."Id", q2."Id", COUNT(q2."Id") 
FROM "Questionnaires" q
INNER JOIN "QuestionnaireSection" qs ON qs."QuestionnaireId" = q."Id"
INNER JOIN "Sections" s ON s."Id" = qs."SectionId"
INNER JOIN "SectionQuestion" sq ON sq."SectionId" = s."Id"
INNER JOIN "Questions" q2 ON q2."Id" = sq."QuestionId"
GROUP BY q."Id", q2."Id"
HAVING COUNT(q2."Id") > 1;
```

My model looks like this:

```cs
public class Questionnaire {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public List<QuestionnaireSection> Sections { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionnaireSection {
   public int QuestionnaireId { get; set; }
   public Questionnaire Questionnaire { get; set; }
   public int SectionId { get; set; }
   public Section Section { get; set; }
}

public class Section {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public List<SectionQuestion> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class SectionQuestion {
   public int SectionId { get; set; }
   public Section Section { get; set; }
   public int QuestionId { get; set; }
   public Question Question { get; set; }
}

public class Question {
   public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and the DbContext has `Questionnaires`, `Sections` and `Questions` `DbSet<>` accessible.

Comment: You have `SectionQuestion` class but it is not used by any other entity.

Comment: Oops, typing error, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is query with navigation properties:

```cs
var query = 
    from q in ctx.Questionnaires
    from qs in q.Sections
    from q2 in qs.Section.Questions 
    group q by new { q.Id, Q2Id = q2.QuestionId } into gr
    where gr.Count() > 1
    select new
    {
        gr.Key.Id,
        gr.Key.Q2Id,
        Cnt = gr.Count()
    };
```

Comment: Yes, was trying something like that but for some reason was not able to make it work so went with the join approach.

Comment: Had to "fix" `from qs in q.QuestionnaireSection` to `from qs in q.Sections` (I'll edit the answer), but it worked. Thanks!

Any way to write that in EF Code (i.e. `await ctx.Questionnaires.Include(....` instead of Linq to SQL?

Comment: `Include` will not work here. It has different purpose - loading related entities ONLY. We can convert this query to Method syntax but it will be ugly as a hell. If you have two or more tables involved in query better to use Query syntax.

Comment: Still, I'm curious how that would work with "Method syntax"? I got it with the `join()` from Guru Stron's answer (and yes, it's uglyish), but this here got me stumped because of the multiple `from`.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would just expose the join entities (since you have decided to define them explicitly) but if you don't want - just use `DbContext.Set` method:

```cs
var query = from q in ctx.Questionnaires
    join qs in ctx.Set<QuestionnaireSection>()
        on q.Id equals qs.QuestionnaireId
    join s in ctx.Sections on qs.SectionId equals s.Id
    join sq in ctx.Set<SectionQuestion>() on s.Id equals sq.SectionId
    join q2 in ctx.Questions on sq.QuestionId equals q2.Id
    select new { q.Id, Q2Id = q2.Id }
    into tmp
    group tmp by new { tmp.Id, tmp.Q2Id }
    into gr
    where gr.Count() > 1
    select new
    {
        gr.Key.Id,
        gr.Key.Q2Id,
        Cnt = gr.Count()
    };
```

In Method syntax, it would look like:

```cs
var duplicates = await ctx.Questionnaires.Join(
        inner: ctx.Set<QuestionnaireSection>(),
        innerKeySelector: x => x.QuestionnaireId,
        outerKeySelector: x => x.Id,
        resultSelector: (q, s) => new { QuestionnaireId = q.Id, s.SectionId }
    )
    .Join(
        inner: ctx.Sections,
        innerKeySelector: x => x.Id,
        outerKeySelector: x => x.SectionId,
        resultSelector: (t, s) => new { t.QuestionnaireId, t.SectionId }
    )
    .Join(
        inner: ctx.Set<SectionQuestion>(),
        innerKeySelector: x => x.SectionId,
        outerKeySelector: x => x.SectionId,
        resultSelector: (t, q) => new { t.QuestionnaireId, q.QuestionId }
    )
    .Join(
        inner: ctx.Set<Question>(),
        innerKeySelector: x => x.Id,
        outerKeySelector: x => x.QuestionId,
        resultSelector: (t, q) => new { t.QuestionnaireId, QuestionId = q.Id }
    )
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.QuestionnaireId, x.QuestionId })
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .Select(x => new { x.Key.QuestionnaireId, x.Key.QuestionId, Count = x.Count() })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I think better to use navigation properties instead of joins.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, how would you do that with navigation properties instead of joins?

Comment: @Guru Stron Thanks, that's works. I'll rewrite as EF Core code to avoid having only one place is my code with Linq-to-SQL. But you say "since you have decided to define them explicitly", for the N-to-N entities? I could have decided not the expose them?! How? Any link to documentation?

Comment: @dstj Was glad to help! For fully defined relationships you can skip the explicit join one - see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#basic-many-to-many) (though personally I prefer explicit one) and EF Core will generate the join table based on conventions.